# Angular 8 table row rendering directive issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I have a table that renders data. In each column header, I have added a 'sortableHeaderName' directive. The purpose of the directive is to fire a sort event to the component that renders the table so as to add appropriate font awesome arrow-up/down action based on the sortDirection('asc', 'desc', ' '(retrieve the original data on the third click)). The issue I believe is the directive is not able to realize the element that is clicked, it is not able to render the original data on 3rd click. If I use the same directive code with all the table data manually instead of using the loop everything is running fine (3rd click on the header name renders the original order of the data and the font awesome icon is removed)

-----------HTML row rendering -----------------------

```
<tr>

    <th scope="col" sortableHeaderName="rowNum" (sort)="onSort($event)">

      #

    </th>

    <th *ngFor="let dispute of allDisputes[0] | keyvalue;" scope="col"

        sortableHeaderName={{disputeTableHeaderDetails[dispute.key]?.sortHeaderName}}

        (sort)="onSort($event)"

        id="{{dispute.key}}"

    >

      <i *ngIf="disputeTableHeaderDetails[dispute.key]?.sortHeaderName === currentColName" [ngClass]=className></i>

      <span copyClipboard>{{disputeTableHeaderDetails[dispute.key]?.colName}}</span>

    </th>

  </tr>




//-----------directive code-----------------




import {
    Directive,
    Input,
    Output,
    EventEmitter,
    ElementRef
   } from '@angular/core';



   import {
    SortDirection
   } from 'src/app/constants/AppConstants';

   import {
    SortEvent
   } from '../models/sort-event.model';



   @Directive({

    selector: 'th[sortableHeaderName]',

    host: {

     '(click)': 'performRotation()'

    }

   })

   export class SortableHeaderDirective {

    rotate: {
     [key: string]: SortDirection
    } = {
     asc: 'desc',
     desc: '',
     '': 'asc'
    };

    @Input() sortableHeaderName: string;

    // @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';

    direction: SortDirection = '';

    @Output() sort = new EventEmitter < SortEvent > ();

    currDirection: string = null;

    clickCount = 0;



    constructor() {

    }



    performRotation() {

     // this.direction = this.rotate[this.direction];

     // if (this.currDirection) {

     //   this.currDirection = this.rotate[this.currDirection];

     // } else {

     //   this.currDirection = this.rotate.desc;

     // }

     this.clickCount += 1;



     switch (this.clickCount) {

      case 1:

       this.currDirection = 'asc';

       break;



      case 2:

       this.currDirection = 'desc';

       break;



      case 3:

       this.currDirection = '';

       break;



      default:

       this.clickCount = 0;

       break;

     }



     // this.currDirection = this.currDirection ? this.rotate[this.currDirection] : this.rotate[this.direction];



     this.sort.emit({
      column: this.sortableHeaderName,
      direction: this.currDirection
     });

    }

   }
```

Comment: I have written a library called Easy Angular that provides a table component https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez Here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5 you could either use the table component or look through the source code for ideas. My up and down sort arrows are 100% CSS working off the aria tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am looking for some to point out my mistake